# htaccess rewrite rule containing certain word

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a magento web shop and i use a plugin to import stock, prices, products. Annoyingly this plugin doesnt save old urls if i update the product name etc.
Is there a way i can do this with htaccess? For example, i removed the SKU from the end of a product URL but google has indexed some of these old URLs.

Is it possible to rewrite `https://www.example.com/xerox-everyday-toner-for-tn242y-yellow-toner-cartridge-006r04226` to `https://www.example.com/xerox-everyday-toner-for-tn242y-yellow-toner-cartridge` using some wildcards? Obviously everything before the word "cartridge" changes per product so i want a redirect that if a URL contains "-cartridge-" remove everything after that pattern as SKU lengths can change but only contain alphanumeric characters. If a URL does not contain "-cartridge-" do not do anything.
I've tried a few regex patterns using an online htaccess builder but i cant seem to get this correct (unless these sites dont process the regex and thats why i think they dont work).

Comment: `RewriteRule (.+-cartridge)-.+$ $1 [R=301,L]` should probably do. (Test with `R=302` first, so that if anything doesn't work, you don't have to deal with redirects being cached by your browser)

Comment: This seems to be the answer, thanks. As suggested i am trying with a 302 first, but initial tests are positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule (.+-cartridge)-.+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This should do the job. Everything up to `-cartridge` gets captured (capturing the dynamic part before and this static suffix in one go, means we don't have the assemble the substitution URL out of multiple parts, but can just use `$1`), and after it a `-` plus some arbitrary characters must follow.

> is there anyway you can add a rule so it excludes if "multipack" comes after the "-cartridge-".

The often easiest way to do this, is to place a "do nothing" rule *before* the one that does the rewriting. Then you can work with a *positive* match ("if URL ends in `-cartridge-multipack`, do nothing"), instead of trying to find a negated pattern.

```
RewriteRule -cartridge-multipack$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+-cartridge)-.+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Pattern anchored at the end with `$` (means nothing is allowed to come after this), `-` for "no substitution", and the `L` flag to make the rewrite engine stop the current round of processing.

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer, but is there anyway you can add a rule so it excludes if "multipack" comes after the "-cartridge-". I forgot i had some URLs that have "ink-cartridge-multipack" that i need to exclude. I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^multipack$` before the rule but that didnt work

Comment: @AlexSmith check the edit, please, that should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I think that works, i just need to find the right place in the magento .htaccess file to put it due to the other rules in place

Comment: As an external redirect, this should probably be placed pretty high up. If you got any general http-to-https or www-to-non-www (/vice versa) redirects, those should happen first, and then this one after. It should happen before any internal rewrites start.

Comment: Oddly, if i put it at the very top of the .htaccess in the root directly the multipack rule doesnt work, it causes it error 404, any further down in that file means neither rule works. In another .htaccess (with other magento rules) too high up and it has the same issue, and any further down i have the same issue as before (including pub/ in the URL which is a rule magento add in as thats where content is served from now).
I've posted in the magento stackexchange as its more their thing